# backup virtualbox VM installations and migrate to windows 7

Tags: virtualbox

I'm currently running on vista 64 home premium, using virtual box 32bit (there isnt a win64 release to my knowledge)

I'm soon upgrading my host system to windows 7 64 home premium, is there a way to backup all my virtualbox setups, so I can just re-import them when I have upgraded my host OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the folder that you keep all of the VMs in. When you reinstall just copy the folder back and point VirtualBox at it.

Comment: Thanks. For Vista users VB puts them under : C:\Users\James\.VirtualBox by default